# funkload benchmark test failure

Tags: python, testing, funkload

I am testing my Python script with `funkload`.

I use this command :

```
fl-run-bench -c 1:2 test_RecuperationPhotos.py RecuperationPhotos.test_RecPhotos
```

I have this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/fl-run-bench", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('collective.funkload==0.3', 'console_scripts', 'fl-run-bench')()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 343, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2354, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2060, in load
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/collective/funkload/bench.py", line 8, in <module>
    from zope.testing.testrunner import runner
ImportError: cannot import name runner
```

I cannot understand what the error means.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a situation with the installation of funkload. I had the same issue last month.